# Bukkit/Spigot how to obtain player custom head ID

Tags: java, bukkit

I am attempting to get the SkullOwner ID and the texture value out of any placed player skull but I can't figure out any method. The best thing I have gotten is merely the username of a player head that didn't require such IDs (basically meaning one that uses `{SkullOwner:"PLAYERNAME"}`, like for example the one obtained by doing `/give @p skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"Notch"}`)

This is my code so far

```
package me.saltyhelpvampire.spigotmushroom;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.BlockState;
import org.bukkit.block.Skull;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class SpigotMushroom extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        System.out.println("This is a generic message");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onMushroomheadPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (event.getBlock().getType() == Material.SKULL) {
                event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Player placed head");
                BlockState block = event.getBlock().getState();
                if(block instanceof Skull) {
                    Skull skull = (Skull) block;
                    String owner = skull.getOwner();
                    event.getPlayer().sendMessage(owner);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why exactly isn't this working?

Comment: It should output the SkullOwner ID and the texture value using "sendMessages" but currently it simply outputs the name of a player and only if the head doesn't require an ID

Comment: After some research I did later, I discovered I only need the texture information from the block, which I think is obtained from `SkullMeta` or some other method of `Skull` unknown to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Minecraft if a skull is placed with only playername as a nbt value, the client loads the skin data and not the server, you have to use the mojang api for that, there you can convert the name into a UUID and then get the texture of that UUID

Comment: That makes sense. I found a workaround but it's good to know, it may be useful in the future